# O que é cache no contexto da Web?

Tags: terminologia, cache

Muitas vezes é dito: "Ah, isso fica armazenado no *cache*..."

Onde o navegador armazena seu *cache*, existe um tamanho limite e tem alguma relação com o *Local Storage*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O LocalStorage pode ser usado para fazer um cache para seu site de forma que você controle, mas não é sua função primária.

Os dados colocados no cache devem ser considerados temporários e nada garante que eles estarão presentes em algum momento. Em tese o LocalStorage deveria ser usado para dados "permanentes".

O cache é um mecanismo que permite acessar algum dado de forma mais rápida porque está em um meio mais próximo, ou que oferece melhor desempenho, ou porque não precisa fazer algo que já foi feito antes.

No caso da web ele é usado pelo navegador para manter tudo o que já foi carregado uma vez e não precisar buscar novamente em outra máquina, que é uma operação que gera tráfego e responde de forma mais lenta, afinal redes como a internet estão mais longe e costumam ser mais lentas que a sua própria máquina. Não tem porque pedir de novo algo que já foi pedido.

Então ele é um repositório de arquivos requisitados pelo navegador, em geral disposto em uma ou mais pastas com todos esses arquivos. Pegar o que está ali no disco tende a ser mais rápido que pedi-lo pela internet. Normalmente o que está sendo usado naquele momento fica na memória para ser ainda mais rápido, já que memória é mais rápida que o disco.

É comum o navegador perguntar se determinado arquivo no servidor tem uma versão mais nova que a armazenada no cache para poder atualizá-lo. Também é comum que esta consulta só seja feita depois de expirar sua validade. Quando não se administra bem a validade há alguns problemas frequentemente relados aqui e em outros lugares dizendo que mudou uma página mas o navegador ainda carrega a antiga.

O limite de tamanho do cache pode existir se o navegador desejar, este é um controle dele. Ele também pode ir apagando o que está lá há muito tempo depois que atinge um determinado consumo. É comum os navegadores permitirem configurar esse limite.

Pelo menos esse é o cache mais comum quando se fala em web. Existem caches de servidores, mas acho que não é o foco da pergunta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).